# Cannot label two mobile numbers as mobile on one contact

Tags: ios, contacts

I try to label two cell/mobile numbers on one contact but the second will not accept the "Mobile" label and shows "Home".  Hence there is no message bubble to send message from second mobile number.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Works well for me. The first time I put in the second number, it made it into a "Home" number, but when I edited the contract again and changed it to "Mobile" again, then it works just like it's supposed to.

What version if iOS are you running? I'm running iOS 8.4 (I need to update to 8.4.1) on my iPhone 5S. The only thing that I can think of is a bug in the version of iOS that you're running.

Comment: That would work - but what if you use Siri to dial? I'd far rather name them 'mobile' & 'other mobile' [or some other memorable & distinguishing word or phrase]. Of course, if one's an iPhone, you've a ready-made tag to use ;-)